# Remove objects from list based on equal property and comparison of time/date

Tags: java

Say I have an object Person with the following properties:

```
public class Person {
   private int customerNumber
   private java.sql.Date birthday
   private java.sql.Time birthTime
}
```

CustomerNumber is not a unique field and many person's can share the same number.

And now if I have a collection of these Person objects stored in a list `List<Person> persons` and I would like to remove persons with the same customer number based on their birthday/time so that if there are two (or more) person's with the same customerNumber, the one who was born first should remain in the list and the other one(s) should be removed.

For example, if the person list would contain the following objects:

```
[{customerNumber: 123, birthday: '1970-10-21', birthTime: '18:20:10'},
 {customerNumber: 123, birthday: '1975-10-21', birthTime: '18:20:10'},
 {customerNumber: 123, birthday: '1970-10-21', birthTime: '10:00:00'},
 {customerNumber: 456, birthday: '1990-02-15', birthTime: '14:50:20'}]
```

After doing some magic, I should be left with the following list:

```
[{customerNumber: 123, birthday: '1970-10-21', birthTime: '10:00:00'},
 {customerNumber: 456, birthday: '1990-02-15', birthTime: '14:50:20'}]
```

Because there are 3 persons with the same customer number (123) but the third one from top was born first (based on date + time) so s/he should remain in the list while the other two should be removed.

Comment: Show us *your* magic code.

Comment: Override `hashCode()` and `equals()` method in `Person` class.

Comment: Idea: Stream the list, group them by `customerNumber`, sort each group by `birthday` + `birthtime`, keep the first.

Comment: @SudhirOjha That will not give you the first (= with the earliest birthday/time) of the persons being equal.

Comment: @LutzHorn The "magic code" is something that I am looking for here :D i.e. how would you solve this?

Comment: What code have you written till now??

Comment: @LutzHorn Sorry all, I'm still more or less new to Stack overflow and wasn't aware that I should accept an answer (feel kinda stupid now...). Anyway thank you all for your answers and I try to come up with a solution regarding my question above :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have the corresponding getters and setters, you may try something like below:

```
List<Person> unique = persons.stream()
                     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getCustomerNumber)) //returns a Map<String,List<Person>> with customerNumber as key
                     .values()
                     .stream()   // stream and sort each list 
                     .map(e-> e.stream().sorted(
                        Comparator.comparing(Person::getBirthday)
                                  .thenComparing(Person::getBirthTime))
                       .findFirst().get())    // map to first Person obj
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());  

unique.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Really elegant code and works just as expected. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It might be slow because am using two loops but you can use similar to this one

```
public List<Person> removeDuplicate(List<person> personList){

    Iterator<Person> itr = personList.iterator();
    boolean isRemoved = false;

    while (itr.hasNext()) {

        Person item = (Person) itr.next();

        for(Person element: personList){
              //i am assuming you have a getter method for all your properties in Person class
             if(element.getCustomerNumber() == item.getcustomerNumber()){

                 if(element.getBirthday().compare(item.getBirthday() < 0){

                     itr.remove();
                     isRemoved = true;
                     break; 
                  }  
              }
         }

        if(isRemoved){

           Continue;      
         }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved by using a hashMap and a compare method similar to that implemented in Person class.
I tried following program and it worked for me.

```
 import java.sql.Date;
    import java.sql.Time;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;

    public class P3 {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // Create sample data.
            List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
            persons.add(new Person(1, new Date(2019, 1, 5), new Time(2, 0, 0)));
            persons.add(new Person(1, new Date(2019, 1, 5), new Time(4, 0, 0)));
            persons.add(new Person(1, new Date(2019, 1, 5), new Time(5, 0, 0)));
            persons.add(new Person(1, new Date(2019, 1, 5), new Time(1, 0, 0)));
            persons.add(new Person(2, new Date(2019, 1, 5), new Time(2, 0, 0)));

            // Create map with unique customer number.
            Map<Integer, Person> map = new HashMap<>();
            for(Person person : persons) {
                if(map.containsKey(person.getCustomerNumber())) {
                    int eleToBeRemoved = Person.compare(map.get(person.getCustomerNumber()), person);
                    if(eleToBeRemoved == 1) {
                        map.remove(person.getCustomerNumber());
                        map.put(person.getCustomerNumber(), person);
                    }
                } else {
                    map.put(person.getCustomerNumber(), person);
                }
            }

            persons = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
            for(Person person : persons) {
                System.out.println(person);
            }


        }

    }

    class Person {

        private int customerNumber;
        private java.sql.Date birthday;
        private java.sql.Time birthTime;

        public Person() {
        }

        public Person(int customerNumber, Date birthday, Time birthTime) {
            this.customerNumber = customerNumber;
            this.birthday = birthday;
            this.birthTime = birthTime;
        }

        public int getCustomerNumber() {
            return customerNumber;
        }

        public void setCustomerNumber(int customerNumber) {
            this.customerNumber = customerNumber;
        }

        public java.sql.Date getBirthday() {
            return birthday;
        }

        public void setBirthday(java.sql.Date birthday) {
            this.birthday = birthday;
        }

        public java.sql.Time getBirthTime() {
            return birthTime;
        }

        public void setBirthTime(java.sql.Time birthTime) {
            this.birthTime = birthTime;
        }


        public static int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
            if(p1.getCustomerNumber() == p2.getCustomerNumber()) {
                int birthdayComp = p1.getBirthday().compareTo(p2.getBirthday());
                if(birthdayComp == 0) {
                    int timeComp = p1.getBirthTime().compareTo(p2.getBirthTime());
                    if(timeComp == 0) {
                        return 2;
                    } else if(timeComp < 0) {
                        return 2;
                    } else {
                        return 1;
                    }
                } else if(birthdayComp < 0) {
                    return 2;
                } else {
                    return 1;
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Person [customerNumber=" + customerNumber + ", birthday=" + birthday + ", birthTime=" + birthTime + "]";
        }

    }
```